# How to configure Nhibernate in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am a beginner in ASP.Net. I am starting a new project using ASP.Net and Nhibernate. I figured out that the hibernate.cfg.xml would not do the trick for the configuration of Nhibernate. I googled for on how to configure NHibernate in ASP.Net and [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+nhibernate+configure&hl=en&start=10&sa=N) is simplest that I got but I can't get it to work. I also downloaded some projects using ASP.Net and Nhibernate but can't seem to understand how it is configured. And so I am here asking for your opinion/knowledge.
How do you configure HHibernate in an ASP.Net project? or can you please provide a link to
tutorial on how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some resources that helped me when I first did an ASP.NET project with nHibernate.

- [Intro and Configuration](https://www.hibernate.org/363.html)
- [Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateArchitecture.aspx)
- [Best Practices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx)

Good luck and great choice!

Answer (score 0):

If you are really starting the most simple way to start is
trunk\nhibernate\src\NHibernate.Example.Web
or
branch\2.1.x\nhibernate\src\NHibernate.Example.Web

link: http://code.google.com/p/nhprofile/downloads/list